# UniDic-2.3.0でMeCabのユーザー辞書をコンパイルする時、左と右の文脈IDの選択方法をお教えください。

Tags: ubuntu, mecab

Ubuntu 20.10の環境で、最新バージョンの[UniDic-CWJ-2.3.0](https://unidic.ninjal.ac.jp/download)で[MeCab 0.996](http://taku910.github.io/mecab/)のユーザー辞書を作成したいですが、エラーが出ます。

下記を実行しました。

```
$ /usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -d /usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0 -u ~/foo/bar/foo.dic -f utf8 -t utf8 ~/foo/bar/foo.csv
```

foo.csvは下記です。

```
ダイバーシティ,,,-200,名詞,普通名詞,一般,*,*,*,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ-diversity,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,外,*,*,*,*,*,*,体,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,,,,,
```

[MeCabの説明書](https://taku910.github.io/mecab/dic.html)によって、左文脈IDと右文脈IDは「空にしておくとmecab-dict-indexが自動的にIDを付与します」が、下記のエラーが出ました。

```
dictionary.cpp(355) [cid->left_size() == matrix.left_size() && cid->right_size() == matrix.right_size()] Context ID files(/usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0/left-id.def or /usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0/right-id.def may be broken
```

下記のURLで似ている問題がありますが、解決方法は書いてありません。
https://github.com/taku910/mecab/issues/42

しかし、旧バージョンの[unidic-mecab-2.1.2](https://unidic.ninjal.ac.jp/back_number#unidic_bccwj)で辞書をコンパイルすることができます。

```
$ /usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -d ~/mecab/unidic-mecab-2.1.2_src/ -u ~/foo/bar/foo.dic -f utf8 -t utf8 ~/foo/bar/foo.csv
./pos-id.def is not found. minimum setting is used
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
done!
```

[unidic-py](https://github.com/polm/unidic-py/tree/master/extras)からのreiwa.33.csvを使ったら、最新バージョンのUniDic 2.3.0でMeCabの辞書をコンパイルすることもできます。

```
/usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -d /usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0 -u ~/foo/bar/reiwa33.dic -f utf8 -t utf8 ~/foo/bar/reiwa.33.csv
/usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0/pos-id.def is not found. minimum setting is used
reading /home/foo/bar/reiwa.33.csv ... 3
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
done!
```

reiwa.33.csvは下記です。

```
令和,4786,4786,8205,名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,レイワ,令和,令和,レーワ,令和,レーワ,固,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,"1,0",*,*,*,*
㋿,5969,5969,2588,補助記号,一般,*,*,*,*,,㋿,㋿,,㋿,,記号,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,,,*,*,*,*,999999
㋿,4786,4786,3992,名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,レイワ,令和,㋿,レーワ,㋿,レーワ,固,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,"1,0",*,*,*,*
```

foo.csvとreiwa.33.csvの違いは、reiwa.33.csvに左文脈IDと右文脈IDが書いてあります。

ですから、左文脈IDと右文脈IDが必要みたいです。

左文脈IDと右文脈IDの選択方法をご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アサーションに失敗しているのは以下の `CHECK_DIE(cid->left_size() == ...` の部分です。

**dictionary.cpp**

```cpp
if (!cid.get()) {
  cid.reset(new ContextID);
  cid->open(left_id_file.c_str(),
            right_id_file.c_str(), &config_iconv);
  CHECK_DIE(cid->left_size()  == matrix.left_size() &&
            cid->right_size() == matrix.right_size())
      << "Context ID files("
      << left_id_file
      << " or "
      << right_id_file << " may be broken";
}
```

`cid->left_size()` が左文脈IDの個数, `cid->right_size()` が右文脈IDの個数です。また、`matrix.left_size()` と `matrix.right_size()` は UniDic の `matrix.def` ファイルの1行目に書かれている数値です(文脈IDは `0` から始まるので `+1` になっています)。ただ、`matrix.bin` ファイルが存在する場合は、そちらを優先的に読み込みます(内容は `matrix.def` と同一)。

```sh
$ tail -1 unidic-cwj-2.3.0/left-id.def
18291 連体詞,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,混,*,*,*,4,*,*
$ tail -1 unidic-cwj-2.3.0/right-id.def
20489 連体詞,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,混,*,*,*,4,*,*
$ head -1 unidic-cwj-2.3.0/matrix.def
20490 18292
```

デバッグオプション(`-g`)を付けて MeCab をビルドして、gdb で実行経過をトレースします。

```sh
$ gdb /usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index
                 :

(gdb) break dictionary.cpp:352
(gdb) run -d /var/tmp/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0 -u foo.dic -f utf8 -t utf8 foo.csv
                 :

Breakpoint 1, MeCab::Dictionary::compile (param=...,
    dics=std::vector of length 1, capacity 1 = {...}, output=0x7fffffffdc90 "foo.dic")
    at dictionary.cpp:352
352               cid.reset(new ContextID);
(gdb) next 2
(gdb) p cid
$1 = {
  _vptr.scoped_ptr = 0x7ffff7fa4810 <vtable for MeCab::scoped_ptr<MeCab::ContextID>+16>, ptr_ = 0x55555556aef0}
(gdb) p cid.ptr_.left_.size()
$2 = 18292
(gdb) p cid.ptr_.right_.size()
$3 = 20490

(gdb) p matrix.lsize_
$4 = 20490
(gdb) p matrix.rsize_
$5 = 18292
```

`matrix.left_size()` と `matrix.right_size()` が逆になっている事が判ります。これは `connector.cpp` で設定されています。

**connector.cpp**

```cpp
bool Connector::open(const char* filename,
                     const char *mode) {
  CHECK_FALSE(cmmap_->open(filename, mode))
      << "cannot open: " << filename;

  matrix_ = cmmap_->begin();

  CHECK_FALSE(matrix_) << "matrix is NULL" ;
  CHECK_FALSE(cmmap_->size() >= 2)
      << "file size is invalid: " << filename;

  lsize_ = static_cast<unsigned short>((*cmmap_)[0]);
  rsize_ = static_cast<unsigned short>((*cmmap_)[1]);
                     :
```

左、右の順序で読み込んでいますが、先程示した様に、`matrix.def` では右、左の順序になっています。

```sh
$ tail -1 unidic-cwj-2.3.0/left-id.def
18291 連体詞,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,混,*,*,*,4,*,*
$ tail -1 unidic-cwj-2.3.0/right-id.def
20489 連体詞,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,混,*,*,*,4,*,*
$ head -1 unidic-cwj-2.3.0/matrix.def
20490 18292
```

そこで `matrix.def`, `unk.def`, `lex.csv` の右・左文脈IDを入れ替えます。

```sh
$ awk 'NR==1{print $2, $1}NR>1{print $2, $1, $3}' matrix.def > matrix.def.reverse_lr
$ mv matrix.def matrix.def.org
$ ln -sf matrix.def.reverse_lr matrix.def
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, '{tmp=$2;$2=$3;$3=tmp;print}' unk.def > unk.def.reverse_lr
$ mv unk.def unk.def.org
$ ln -sf unk.def.reverse_lr unk.def
$ awk -vFPAT='([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")' -vOFS=, '{tmp=$2;$2=$3;$3=tmp;print}' lex.csv > lex.csv.reverse_lr
$ mv lex.csv lex.csv.org
$ ln -sf lex.csv.reverse_lr lex.csv
```

`matrix.bin` などを再作成します(2~3時間程度かかるかもしれません)。

```sh
$ /usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -f utf8 -t utf8 -m matrix.def
```

`foo.csv` の中身は以下の様にします(`unidic` 形式)。

**foo.csv**

```
ダイバーシティ,,,-200,名詞,普通名詞,一般,*,*,*,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ-diversity,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,外,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
```

`foo.dic` を作成して形態素解析を行います。

```sh
$ /usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -d unidic-cwj-2.3.0 -u foo.dic -f utf8 -t utf8 foo.csv

$ printf 'ダイバーシティとは何ですか？' | mecab -d unidic-cwj-2.3.0 -u foo.dic
ダイバーシティ 名詞,普通名詞,一般,,,,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ-diversity,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,外,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
と   助詞,格助詞,,,,,ト,と,と,ト,と,ト,和,,,,,,,格助,ト,ト,ト,ト,,名詞%F1,動詞%F1,形容詞%F2@-1,,7099014038299136,25826
は   助詞,係助詞,,,,,ハ,は,は,ワ,は,ワ,和,,,,,,,係助,ハ,ハ,ハ,ハ,,動詞%F2@0,名詞%F1,形容詞%F2@-1,,8059703733133824,29321
何   代名詞,,,,,,ナニ,何,何,ナニ,何,ナニ,和,,,,,,,体,ナニ,ナニ,ナニ,ナニ,0,1,,,7674599819059712,27920
です  助動詞,,,,助動詞-デス,終止形-一般,デス,です,です,デス,です,デス,和,,,,,,,助動,デス,デス,デス,デス,,形容詞%F2@-1,動詞%F2@0,名詞%F2@1,,7051468750332587,25653
か   助詞,副助詞,,,,,カ,か,か,カ,か,カ,和,,,,,,,副助,カ,カ,カ,カ,,動詞%F2@0,形容詞%F2@-1,名詞%F1,,1530528809492992,5568
？   補助記号,句点,,,,,,？,？,,？,,記号,,,,,,,補助,,,,,,,,15676664324608,57
EOS
```

Comment: 詳しくご説明いただきどうもありがとうございました。つまり、この問題はUniDic2.3.0のバグのせいでしょうか。

Comment: 右と左を取り違えのたのでしょうかね…？ なお、旧バージョンのunidic-mecab-2.1.2では左文脈IDファイル(`left-id.def`)と右文脈IDファイル(`right-id.def`)は全く同じ内容になっているのでこの問題は発生しないのです。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。すみませんが質問をもう一つお伺いしたいのですが、もし```matrix.def```, ```unk.def```, ```lex.def``` の右・左文脈IDを入れ替えず、自分で```left-id.def```と```right-id.def```を読んで、```foo.csv```に手動で左文脈IDと右文脈IDを設定したら、MeCabの形態素解析に影響がありませんでしょうか。

Comment: はい、右と左を入れ替えて設定すれば問題はないはずです。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。不明確な質問をしてしまい、すみませんでした。聞きたかったのは、UniDic 2.3.0の右と左の入れ替えなかったら、ユーザー辞書以外、MeCabの形態素解析に影響がありますでしょうか。

Comment: 今回の件でソースコードを眺めた範囲内では全て左・右の順序で読み込んでいますので、影響はないと思われます。ただ、見落としている部分があるかもしれませんので、UniDic の配布元に報告しておいた方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: どうもありがとうございました。理解いたしました。